# SSRS budget table joined to cases of demo data

Tags: sql-server

This is probalby a simple question, but I don't fully understand what is going wrong..with the method I am using..SoI've gone back to the original two tables that need to be used. So if you can suggest how to tackle this from the outset, would be greatly appreciated. 
One table is cases, that holds individual case details, with dates that can be used to calculate, how long a hire went on for and the rate applied. It has a Source ID, that it has in common with a budget table. Every case has a Source ID. The other table is budget by Source ID for each calendar month. Need to compare the actual income from the dates, and rates in cases and add them and compare, the actual against budget.

The dates used to calculate the duration is the actual start date to the actual end date, but to further complicate matters, only the days of hire in the month of interest are required to be returned. So if a hire started earlier , than the month in question, just those dates are to be compared against the budget for that month.
The only other requirement is to set the rate dependent on the name  of the company, either contract rate or hire daily rate. But i tried to keep it simple as possible.

It's all demo data...

```
USE [AutoHires]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblBudget]    Script Date: 22/01/2018 09:57:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBudget](
    [Ref] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BudgetRevenue] [money] NULL,
    [BudgetHires] [int] NULL,
    [BudgetSold] [int] NULL,
    [BudgetInstructions] [int] NULL,
    [SourceGroup] [int] NULL,
    [MonthFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [MonthTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Budget] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Ref] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (1, 1, 300.0000, 12, 45, 80, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCEA')
INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (2, 2, 400.0000, 15, 50, 90, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCEB')
INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (3, 3, 700.0000, 4, 6, 50, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCEH')
INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (4, 4, 323.0000, 6, 18, 50, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCEG')
INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (5, 5, 567.0000, 6, 45, 56, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCEF')
INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (6, 6, 566.0000, 12, 56, 67, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCEE')
INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (7, 7, 566.0000, 23, 12, 44, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCED')
INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] ([Ref], [SourceID], [BudgetRevenue], [BudgetHires], [BudgetSold], [BudgetInstructions], [SourceGroup], [MonthFrom], [MonthTo], [Name]) VALUES (8, 8, 668.0000, 3, 44, 23, NULL, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'SOURCEC')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblBudget] OFF
```

Second table of cases.

```
 GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCase](
    [PK_RefNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateInstructed] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateClosed] [datetime] NULL,
    [Insurer_tpi] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HireDailyRate] [money] NULL,
    [ActualStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ActualFinishDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [HireContractRate] [money] NULL,
    [DailyRate] [money] NULL,
    [AdditionalCosts] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK_RefNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(N'2017-10-09 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'avg', 2.0000, CAST(N'2017-11-14 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-19 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2.0000, 1.0000, 3.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(N'2017-01-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Bull', 4.0000, CAST(N'2017-01-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, 4.0000, 3.0000, 1.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (3, 3, CAST(N'2017-12-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'bit', 3.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5.0000, 3.0000, 1.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (4, 4, CAST(N'2017-12-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Avast', 5.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5.0000, 4.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (5, 5, CAST(N'2017-12-08 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, N'Kasp', 6.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-22 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 4.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (6, 1, CAST(N'2017-12-06 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'avg', 5.0000, CAST(N'2017-10-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 4.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (7, 1, CAST(N'2017-09-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'avg', 5.0000, CAST(N'2017-11-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-08 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5.0000, 4.0000, 1.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (8, 4, CAST(N'2017-12-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-11 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Avast', 6.0000, CAST(N'2017-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4.0000, 3.0000, 1.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (9, 4, CAST(N'2017-12-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Panda', 6.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 4.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (10, 5, CAST(N'2017-01-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Avast', 7.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-24 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 4.0000, 1.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (11, 8, CAST(N'2017-05-17 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-09-07 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Bull', 3.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5.0000, 3.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (12, 2, CAST(N'2017-01-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-20 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'bit', 5.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-20 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 5.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (13, 8, CAST(N'2017-12-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-20 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Avast', 6.0000, CAST(N'2001-03-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 1.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (14, 8, CAST(N'2017-12-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-19 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Kasp', 5.0000, CAST(N'2017-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 3.0000, 1.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (15, 8, CAST(N'2017-12-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-28 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Panda', 6.0000, CAST(N'2017-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5.0000, 3.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (16, 2, CAST(N'2017-12-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-20 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Avast', 6.0000, CAST(N'2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-19 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5.0000, 1.0000, 2.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (17, 6, CAST(N'2017-12-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Avast', 6.0000, CAST(N'2017-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2017-12-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5.0000, 1.0000, 3.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] ([PK_RefNo], [SourceID], [DateInstructed], [DateClosed], [Insurer_tpi], [HireDailyRate], [ActualStartDate], [ActualFinishDate], [HireContractRate], [DailyRate], [AdditionalCosts]) VALUES (18, 5, CAST(N'2017-12-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Avast', 6.0000, CAST(N'2017-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2018-01-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6.0000, 3.0000, 1.0000)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblCase] OFF
```

If hope you understand the question.

Comment: It's not obvious which dates you refer to in the statement 'with dates that can be used to calculate, how long a hire went on for' possibly actualstartdate,actualfinishdate and presumably you only want to include days hire went on for in december even if the hire dates start before and end after december( or end date is null)

Comment: 'The only other requirement is to set the rate dependent on the name of the company, either contract rate or hire daily rate'  I see no company or any rule to apply if there is one.

Comment: "Insurer_tpi" is the name of the field that determines with rate is applied.

Comment: And the rule for whether contract or hire daily rate applies is?

Comment: Wether the name has "avg" in it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this

```
select * from tblbudget
left join
(
select    
    [SourceID],
        hirevalue = sum((datediff(d,    
        (case when actualstartdate < '2017-12-01' then '2017-12-01' 
            else actualstartdate
        end),
        (case when actualfinishdate > '2017-12-31' or actualfinishdate is null then '2017-12-31'
        else actualfinishdate
        end)
        ) + 1) * (case when Insurer_tpi = 'avg' then hiredailyrate else dailyrate end) )
from tblcase
where   (actualstartdate >= '2017-12-01' and actualstartdate <='2017-12-31') 
        or
        (actualfinishdate >= '2017-12-01' and actualfinishdate <='2017-12-31')
        or 
        (actualstartdate < '2017-12-01' and actualfinishdate > '2017-12-31') 
        or
        (actualstartdate < '2017-12-01' and actualfinishdate is null) 
group by sourceid
) cases on cases.sourceid = tblbudget.Sourceid

Ref         SourceID    BudgetRevenue         BudgetHires BudgetSold  BudgetInstructions SourceGroup MonthFrom               MonthTo                 Name                                               SourceID    hirevalue
----------- ----------- --------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------ ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------
1           1           300.00                12          45          80                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCEA                                            1           306.00
2           2           400.00                15          50          90                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCEB                                            2           44.00
3           3           700.00                4           6           50                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCEH                                            3           45.00
4           4           323.00                6           18          50                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCEG                                            4           253.00
5           5           567.00                6           45          56                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCEF                                            5           209.00
6           6           566.00                12          56          67                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCEE                                            6           30.00
7           7           566.00                23          12          44                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCED                                            NULL        NULL
8           8           668.00                3           44          23                 NULL        2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 SOURCEC                                            8           282.00

(8 row(s) affected)
```